# Create a mac readable / writable fat32 partition

Tags: pi-3, partition

I want an extra partition that I can see both on my mac as well the raspberry pi.

I have been trying this for around 6 hours now...

I installed raspbian from a mac with:

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=/Users/doekewartena/Downloads/2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/disk1
```

There is 1 unallocated partition of 4mb.
1 boot partition of 63mb.
And 1 / partition of 119.02 gb.

I would like to make 2 partitions of the / partition. Half of it the ext4 and the other half a fat32 partition.

How can I do that? I tried it with GParted but it complains the disk is mounted. (Cause the OS is running of it).

I also followed those instructions:

http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/adding-a-fat32-partition-to-raspbian-on-a-rasperry-pi/

But it gave me a partition of 4mb that I couldn't see on my mac.

please help.

Comment: You should try using Gparted offline on another machine running linux or when booted from another SD-Card. Use an USB-SD-Card Reader for that purpose.

Comment: You don't actually say what you did - post your commands NOT a link to some ANCIENT blog. Also post `flist -l` for the SD Card. If you have installed Raspbian and let it auto expand the FS you would need to resize the Raspbian partition (which you can't do on a Mac).